# Screen manager AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy

I use ScreenManager in project. When I return "Home" class in Main.py it works correctly but ı return "ScreenManager" it get AttributeError.How can ı fix it.

#### Main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from Components.Home.HomeScreen import Home,EachTask
from Components.SM.SM import SM
Builder.load_file("Components/SM/SM.kv")
Builder.load_file("Components/Home/HomeScreen.kv")
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM()

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

when I return Home() it works but I return SM is not work

#### HomeScreen.py

```py
class Home(Screen):


def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(Home,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    EachTask.Remove_widget = self.remove_widget
    MyPopup.Remove_widget = self.remove_widget_pop
    EachTask.Do_Popup_Task = self.do_popup_task




    for row in database:


        if (row[3]) == True:
            newListItem = EachTask(rgba=[0, .7, .3, 1],
                                   text= row[0] + "    time:    " + row[1],
                                   id=row[2])
            self.ids.add_field.add_widget(newListItem)

        else:

                newListItem = EachTask(text=row[0] + "    time:    " + row[1],
                                       id=row[2])

                self.ids.add_field.add_widget(newListItem)
```

## Error

```
   self.ids.add_field.add_widget(newListItem)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in 
   kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
   AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable example, you haven't even posted the code for the SM class that's failing somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in stackoverflow. I can send all codes to the your mail adress.

Comment: @I.Bozcan If you want help then provide a [MRE] **here**

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing much to say without looking at the kv file and the py file.
But, just to check

```
self.ids.add_field.add_widget(newListItem)
```

this line would add the `newListItem` to the Layout which is defined in `.kv file`.
the `id:` of the this layout needs to be `add_field` as well

for example (kv file):

```
<Home>:
  GridLayout:
     id:add_field
     cols:2
```